I am using Intel pintool and I want to verify that the original program's code is running in the Code Cache. How can I do this?
#include <iostream>
_declspec(naked) int f() {
    _asm {
        call $ + 5          
        pop eax           
        ret
    }
}
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::hex << "curIp " << f() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

This assembly code only gets the address near the function when it is running.
This program is compiled in 32-bit and returns 0x401025 under normal circumstances, but it also returns 0x401025 when traced by pintool. I am very surprised that the code executed in CodeCache should have different addresses from the code executed by the original program.
The same results were obtained when I verified the Intel pintool CodeCache with exception related code.

"This program is compiled in 32-bit and returns 0x401025 under normal circumstances, but it also returns 0x401025 when traced by pintool." - that looks like the same number to me. Did you copy the wrong value?

Depending on your OS and how you built an executable, ASLR could randomize the address of the whole executable every run.  Or when loading under pintool.  Assuming you actually are getting different addresses, unlike in your question where you have the same number twice.
